# Known a limit equation with $f(x)$ inside, and finding $f(2x)$

Tags: calculus

I kinda confused by this exercise. :
[The Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZBpq.png)
[image]

I am not sure, with limit properties we can divide but still the numerator are zero.

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Let $u = \frac{x}{2}$ which implies $u \to 0$ also. Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{1-\cos x}{f(2x)}= \dfrac{1 - \cos(2x)}{f(2x)}\cdot \dfrac{1-\cos x}{1-\cos (2x)}$